# How to perform NSE on the left hand side of a dplyr function?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, nse

Consider

```r
library(dplyr)
assign_rhs <- function(df, rhs) {
  df %>%
    mutate(lhs = {{rhs}})
}

a = data.frame(b = 1, c = 2)

assign_rhs(a, b)
```

will yields:

```
  b c lhs
1 1 2   1
```

and I can do `assign_rhs(a, c)` as well to assign `lhs` to `c` instead of `b`.

How do I do it so that the `lhs` can also receive the NSE `{{}}` treatment provided by `{rlang}`?

I tried

```r
library(dplyr)
assign_lhs_rhs <- function(df, lhs, rhs) {
  df %>%
    mutate({{lhs}} = {{rhs}})
}

a = data.frame(b = 1, c = 2)

assign_lhs_rhs(lhs, b)
```

but I get error when defining the function

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  df %>%
    mutate({{lhs}} ="
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `:=` instead of `=` you can use NSE on the left-hand side of the assignment:

```
assign_lhs_rhs <- function(df, lhs, rhs) {
    df %>%
        mutate({{lhs}} := {{rhs}})
}

a = data.frame(b = 1, c = 2)

assign_lhs_rhs(a, out, b)
```

Output:

```
  b c out
1 1 2   1
```

I'm not an expert on non-standard evaluation, but as far as I know the reason for this is that it's not possible to override the way `=` works, so it has to be done via a new operator `:=`.